# Are the washer drain and electrical outlets underneath up to code?

Tags: plumbing, drain, washer

My daughter got her washer and dryer only to find out that the water supply/drain is 6 feet from the ground.  Obviously none of the hoses can reach.  I am aware that the maximum height for washer drain is 36"....anything higher can cause overflow/backflow.  The 2 outlets underneath....the left one is the dryer outlet and other is standard non gfci.  The Landlord is crappy and wont put ANY money into ANY repairs.  He said to buy extra long water supply hoses and hang the washer drain pipe into a large trashcan.....being since you don't typically find them that long.  Please breakdown Which code specifies potential problems for this setup.  The Landlord asked why it wasn't code.

What needs to be done to correct this?[image: washer]

Comment: Just because you don't see buttons on it does not mean it is not GFCI.

Comment: If no other options suit you (due to cost, landlord, etc.), a fairly low cost way to proceed while certainly avoiding plumbing issues would be to raise the unit up on a platform. Make the platform deep enough for the operator to stand even with the unit, with steps as necessary to climb onto the platform, and railings if there are a lot of steps. Be sure to frame appropriately, using similar techniques as a deck.

Comment: Is this a single family dwelling (house) or an apartment building?

Comment: Hmm.. my guess is that this was set up for a front-loading washer to be placed on a platform to get it up to a comfortable height for loading.

Comment: It depends when the place was built. My guess Would be it was designed for a stacked washer dryer depending on the age of the house no GFCI may even be required, in fact 2 wire is still legal and you have no right to expect more than what was required to be there when the home was built wow I would have noticed the plumbing being different and I am an electrician.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, I'd consider putting the washer on a platform (can be built pretty quickly), with room for the operator. It's low cost and solves the issue. Have the landlord do it. :) Unless he wants to risk his basement being flooded by backflow from the washer. The basement should support a standard washer.

Answer (score 0):

I would cut and extend the drain hose.  More hose can be purchased from any hardware store with barbed couplings and hose clamps. Then if need be get the longer fill hoses as well.

Comment: But can the machine pump waste water to that height? How much waste water would be left in the pipe? I doubt the machine would have been designed with this height of drain in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Get a small [submersible water pump](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000X07GMW) and rig it with a [float switch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0064BHEVM), then put it into a [covered bucket/trash can](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0798JJLS8) next to the washer then run the washer discharge to the bucket and from the bucket to the drain.

I'm not sure how much waste water the "reservoir bucket" will have to handle with that particular washer, but I would think 7-10 gallons would work. You'd definitely want to check that to be sure. Cut appropriate holes in the lid of the bucket and seal them up appropriately.

There are other pumps and float switches that are, perhaps, better for this application, but I included these as examples of what you might put together. The pump is probably much stronger than what you'd need (maybe a fish pond pump instead?) and there are probably float switches that will work better in a small bucket too.

[image]

Granted, it's not "code" but for a rental, it should cost less than $100 and be good enough to get you through a few years. Better than having dirty water flow back into the washer or all over the floor.

Comment: And then, there's this:
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0009TCDZ2